# Cross-sectional dependence and heteroskedasticity in panel data

Tags: regression, panel-data, heteroscedasticity, covariance-matrix

there are some [previous posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/autocorrelation-and-heteroskedasticity-in-panel-data) dealing with heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation in panel data, nevertheless I have not found any post discussing heteroskedasticity and cross-sectional dependence at the same time.

I am analysing some panel data, which suffer from both aforementioned issues. To deal with a cross-sectional dependence I use a **Driscoll And Kraay (1998) Robust Covariance Matrix Estimator** (function vcovSCC in R). To deal with heteroskedasticity I use a **classic Robust Covariance Matrix** (function vcovHC, specifically method arellano).

Obviously, both methods result in different SE. Is there a way how to account for **both heteroskedasticity and cross-sectional dependence at the same time**? If not, which of these robust cov. matrices should I use?

Cheers,
Adam